# Run my first spark python program error

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been working in spark (hadoop 2.7 based) with Python on eclipse and I am trying to run the sample example "word count" and it is my code :
    # Imports
    # Take care about unused imports (and also unused variables),
    # please comment them all, otherwise, you will get any errors at the execution.
    # Note that neither the directives "@PydevCodeAnalysisIgnore" nor  "@UnusedImport"
    # will be able to solve that issue.
    #from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans
    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
    import os

```
# Configure the Spark environment
sparkConf = SparkConf().setAppName("WordCounts").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf = sparkConf)

# The WordCounts Spark program
textFile = sc.textFile(os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] + "/README.md")
wordCounts = textFile.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).map(lambda word:     (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
for wc in wordCounts.collect(): print wc
```

and then i got the following errors :

```
17/08/07 12:28:13 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop     library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/08/07 12:28:16 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port     4040. Attempting port 4041.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hduser/eclipse-workspace/PythonSpark/src/WordCounts.py", line  12, in <module>
sc = SparkContext(conf = sparkConf)
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 186, in _do_init
self._accumulatorServer = accumulators._start_update_server()
File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 259, in  _start_update_server
server = AccumulatorServer(("localhost", 0), _UpdateRequestHandler)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 417, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 431, in server_bind
self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

any help ?? I can run any project of spark with Scala using spark-shell and also any (non spark ) python program on eclipse with no errors 
i think my problem is with pyspark any things to do ??

Comment: Can you check if your Pyspark shell is running or not ? I think there is an issue with the path for pyspark.

Comment: how can i make this ?

Comment: when i run jps on my EdgeNode i got that  2706 ResourceManager
9717 Jps
2534 SecondaryNameNode
3143 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
2987 SparkSubmit

Answer (score 0):

**You could Try this ,Just Create SparkContext is enough ,its working.**

```
sc = SparkContext()
# The WordCounts Spark program
textFile = sc.textFile("/home/your/path/Test.txt")// OR on File-->right click get the path paste here
wordCounts = textFile.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).map(lambda word:     (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
for wc in wordCounts.collect():
print wc
```

Comment: when i just type sc it says : sc = SparkContext()
NameError: name 'SparkContext' is not defined

Comment: my problem i think is it can,t reach to spark context

Comment: @kingtouch999 are you importing SparkContext? P.S. from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

Answer (score 0):

**Try This way...**

After started your spark it shows on COMMAND PROMPT sc as SparkContext.

If not available you can use following way..

```
>>sc=new org.apache.spark.SparkContext()
>>NOW YOU CAN USE...sc
```

Comment: for sorry no it gives me : sc=new org.apache.spark.SparkContext()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sc=new org.apache.spark.SparkContext()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

**This is enough to run your program.**
Because, sc available your Shell.

First try this your SHEEL MODE...

by line by line...

```
textFile = sc.textFile("/home/your/path/Test.txt")// OR on File-->right click get the path paste here
wordCounts = textFile.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).map(lambda word:     (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
for wc in wordCounts.collect():
print wc
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding the below code should work if Spark is installed properly.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("WordCount")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

input = sc.textFile("file:///sparkcourse/PATH_NAME")
words = input.flatMap(lambda x: x.split())
wordCounts = words.countByValue()

for word, count in wordCounts.items():
    cleanWord = word.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    if (cleanWord):
        print(cleanWord.decode() + " " + str(count))
```